# POM.xml (MAVEN): JAR dependencies Not Found in Referenced Libraries

Tags: hibernate, maven, pom.xml

I'm new to Maven (POM.xml files).

The POM.xml file has all of the required jars.

I even checked the .M2 repository and it also has all the jars file mentioned in POM, but when I explore the project I am not able to find the jar files under the Referenced Libraries.

For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.core}</version>
</dependency>
```

I used the above tag in my POM file. However, when I tried to use @Entity, @Table at class level

i.e. on model class I got the error:
"@Entity/@table can't be resolved as referenced libraries doesn't have hibernate-core jars."

```
POM.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.anand</groupId>
  <artifactId>AnandWebStore</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>AnandWebStore Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.core>4.2.7.Final</hibernate.core>
    </properties>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>  


         <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
           <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.core}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4-2.0</version>
        </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>AnandWebStore</finalName>
  </build>
</project>

.m2 already have all this file downloaded:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkxO4.jpg


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQU8g.jpg
```

[This picture shows pom dependencies and referenced libraries:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAl9K.jpg)

Comment: So How it can be replicated to Referenced liberaries??

Comment: Please build the project with "Run as -> Maven build" clean install and report the errors you get (if any).

Comment: I didn't get any answer on this and then i switched to Eclipse Luna version and it is working for this without any issue.

Comment: Luna is quite outdated. I don't understand why you did not do what I suggested.

Comment: @JFMeier...i tried the same but forgot to comment here about the errors and i was little bit in hurry to start the project thats why i switched the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I am by no means an expert on this.

I *do not have* a solution - I *do have* a **work around**.

The pom file should include those files on the fly when your project is being used.

However, just for the purpose of coding in your IDE you could just download the JAR files you need, and use your IDE settings to manually add the JAR files into the Referenced Libraries.

This way if your IDE gives you autocomplete etc, it will have access to those abilities. It should also stop the compiling errors.

Comment: Hi @jacc734,

yes as a work around it will work but then what is the significance of having maven(pom.xml).

Comment: Hi @HappyPorwal the significance will be that you are not including that .jar file in your compiled result, or your program. The jar file is just for your IDE so you get the nice features such as suggestions, and autocomplete, but the practical use of maven should still be intact, in that you don't need to include the jars you used as dependencies.